# How to add mysql database into project setup.?

Tags: java, mysql

i have a java project with mysql database
i am using advance installer to create a setup file...
i can embed jre to run the software(Without installing java in the system).
like wise,i want to embed the mysql database (system doesn't contains mysql )...
.There is any software to embed mysql database in my project setup...

Comment: There are alternatives databases instead mysql that can go embedded, SQLite as @SLaks said, hsqldb, etc.

Comment: which operating system you are using ?

Comment: @usernaveen: windows 7...

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is very difficult to embed correctly and there are a number of failure states that might occur if it is not shut down using the proper procedure. SQLite is a much better engine for this sort of thing and is used by a number of applications as a persistent backing store. While not as powerful as MySQL, it is much more resilient. It also has the advantage of not requiring a separate process.

SQLite's storage method is to persist things into a file that can be copied, moved, or backed-up without any issues. MySQL involves many such files, some of which are in an inconsistent state unless the correct `FLUSH` is called.

The best you can do with MySQL is *bundle* it, not embed it, but then you'll be responsible for setting it up on the host system, configuring it correctly, running the appropriate maintenance procedures, and providing some kind of back-up facility for the database itself.